# Pulling image into Docker-compose file from docker desktop images?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have installed docker desktop and i have an image when i use the command docker images:

```
JamesGregory@LT-BY1842A489OJ MINGW64 /c/Dev
$docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG  IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
productpricingservice   dev  97be3cef2ce8   5 minutes ago  207MB
```

When i run the command:
`kubectl apply -f "C:\Dockerkubernetes\pricingpod.yaml"`
The pod is created, but i get an error when pulling the image.

```
JamesGregory@LT-BY1842A489OJ MINGW64 /c/Dev
$kubectl get pods
NAME               READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
demo               1/1     Running        0          2d19h
pricingpodworking  0/1     ErrImagePull   0          14s
```

This is my yaml file, how do i get the docker image to be pulled into the compose file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pricingpodworking
spec:
  containers:
  - name: productpricingcontainer
    image: productpricingservice:dev
```

The error i am getting using the desc command is:
`Failed to pull image "productpricingservice": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for productpricingservice, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

It Seems adding your docker desktop name to the front of your image is a requirment e.g. jamesgregor7/imagename:tag.

Comment: Can you post here what's in the links, plz ? (Personally, i don't click on random links posted on the internet) It will probably helps us understand the link you're expecting between docker-compose and kubernetes

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA updated, also included the error thank you.

Comment: A large amount of relevant information sits at the end of 3rd party links or in images. Bring this information into your question in ***textual*** format please, otherwise the next person looking information concerning the problems you are facing will not be able to find your question with search tools.

Comment: @spender the images included in the question are images of my image registry and pods?? the question being asked is clearly obvious!

Comment: @Hawkzey So when I search for "ErrImagePull", this will come up? That's unlikely as the term doesn't appear in your question. Questions/Answers in SO are for the entire community... not just to solve a specific problem for a specific person.

Comment: @spender the error that has come up is clearly stated at the bottom of the question. which is what people will be searching on...

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set `imagePullPolicy: Never` in your container configuration ? Do you still get the error ? (Of course, you need to delete the pod and re-apply the configuration)

Comment: i have just changed my Yaml code to include the username of the docker account and it now works xd jamesgregor7/imagename:tag

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue this week. 
Kubernetes try to pull images (even if is available on the node) because `imagePullPolicy` property has default value `always` 
k8s is trying to do docker login to compare images first. (i am not sure though)

setting up `imagePullPolicy` to `never` or `idNotPresent` for such case worked for me.

Comment: thank you for this, did you happen to have any problems with running apply script, it build the container and pulls the image in correctly now, but the container seems to fail and shows CrashLoopBackOff. my image is a .net core web api image

Comment: @Hawkzey, `kubectl describe <resource_name>` shall provide insight on why you have `CrashLoopBackOff`

Comment: did your container start with docker run command? are you missing command or args? `CrashLoopBackOff` is problem with image i guess.